# How to skip the procedure needed to press any key to exit the exe in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm writing a batch file under windows and I have an executable(*.exe) to perform some tasks

Despite the task I needed have been done

But it seems that the executable has a mechanism to press any key to exit

I can't proceed to execute next line of my batch file

Because I need to execute this .bat by other program automatically

I need to skip this procedure to execute whole .bat

Does it have any method to do this?

Comment: Is your executable a console application or is it a GUI program?  Have you checked the programs documentation to see if there is an option to run the program and automatically exit?  Could you possibly give us a link to the documentation for the program?

Comment: console applications.Sorry for it can't release, but i will check document again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how your executable inputs a keystroke. It may be impossible, but you might try one of the following in your batch file:

```
*executable* < nul
```

or

```
echo x|*executable*
```

(replace "`*executable*`" with the actual name of the executable.)

Comment: You can just use `echo.|*executable*` to send a CRLF to the program.